# microsoft/signalR 404 on negotiate after a while

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm connecting to a .net core `signalR` hub from an `Angular` client (`@microsoft/signalR`).

The connection seems to be successful but every once in a while i get 404 when trying to connect. (`http://myserver:myport/myHub?id=____`)

this is how i build my connection:

```
new signalRBuilder.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl(myUrl)
.**withAutomaticreconnect**([100,5000,10000,15000])
.build.start()
```

I cant figure out why the connection is dropping.

Comment: What is your server setup? Is it multi instance?

Comment: @Brennan no songle instance

Comment: How you map the hub on the server side?

Comment: @Kiril1512 services.AddSignalR(o=>{
o.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);o.HandShakeTimeout= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
})

Comment: On the Configure, you should have something like:
```app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<YourHubImplementation>("/myHub");
            });```